# Does the local part of an e-mail address have a minimum length requirement?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using this expression to validate e-mail addresses:

`"^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$"`

I noticed that in order for the e-mail address to validate, I need to put in at least 3 characters before the @ symbol.  Is this a requirement?  What if I just want to have an e-mail address with 1 or 2 characters before the @ symbol?

Comment: I found this here.  I am not sure how to change it to allow a minimum of 1 character.

Comment: where did you find this on SO?  This REGEX you provide is wrong, for many reasons.

Comment: MS Outlook doesn't prevent you from using `a@b.com`.

Comment: @Brad - I found it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369543/validating-e-mail-with-regular-expression-vb-net/369554#369554

Comment: Basically I just need to check if the user is entering something like a@a.com or a@a.au or a@a.com2

Comment: I find all regex solutions to the problem of validating the structure of an e-mail address to be woefully inadequate. I have quite a number of examples of what some might argue are "edge cases" that are 100% valid. Some forms of notation (comments within `()` and target folder selection via `+` notation) are incredibly useful, but too often artificially restricted because of use of bad regexen such as several demonstrated here. Instead, split and validate the parts. It's a structured value. (Edited to note: but w/o arbitrary limits such as TLD length restrictions.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is entirely possible to have an e-mail address with just one character.  All of the guidelines are defined in RFC822:  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt?number=822

The necessary REGEX:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: How would I change my regular expression to reflect that?

Comment: Yes, that regex is way too long.  The one I have is fine, I just want to allow a minimum of 1 character before the @.

Comment: @Xaisoft, the one you have is **not** fine, it is incorrect.  Suppose I want to use `#` in my e-mail address.

Comment: I found it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369543/validating-e-mail-with-regular-expression-vb-net/369554#369554.  I don't need to cover all bases.

Comment: @Brad: it isn't _perfect_, but I think it's fine--I doubt that a non-negligible amount of people uses a "#" in their email address.

Comment: @Tikhon, your doubts are wrong.  I know several people who use `#` to designate different tags and such in their mailbox.  It is a basic feature that is easy to allow via regex.  There is little excuse for not doing so.

Comment: @Brad: good point. I have never heard of using `#` to do that, but I have seen people use `+`.

Comment: Apparently, it's even possible to have a email address with 0 characters in front of it. Something like `""@example.com`. This is equivalent to having no local part and is valid. See: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.3

Answer (score 2):

**0**, if you don’t count quoting double-quotes. If you do, the minimum’s 1.

> ""@example.com
>
> a@example.com

---

#### [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2)

```
   Mailbox        = Local-part "@" ( Domain / address-literal )

   Local-part     = Dot-string / Quoted-string
                  ; MAY be case-sensitive


   Dot-string     = Atom *("."  Atom)

   Atom           = 1*atext

   Quoted-string  = DQUOTE *QcontentSMTP DQUOTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is bad. You really should change it. Even [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx#paght000001_commonregularexpressions) offers more flexible variant:

```
"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$"
```

Yes, it is long. But you should write good programs, not fast developed programs.

Comment: VMAtm, I get your point, but you must realize that I just found regular expression online and gave it a shot. I never committed to it.

Comment: Should definitely write fast developed programs

Answer (score -2):

I went ahead and decided to use this one:

`"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"`

It allows me to enter 1 or more characters for the local part.

Comment: An explanation of why this was downvoted would be nice.  This is one I found on here, I believe it is from regular-expressions-info.

Comment: What do you mean by quality in this case?  If it is because it does not match certain addresses, I would not define that as quality.  I would say that is more of a quantitative aspect to it.  The regular expression I am looking for does not need to validate every possible address in the world.  If it just had a @ symbol that would be fine.

Comment: This criteria is bad criteria. That's why downvotes, I think.