# How to exclude spaces when using ValidationExpression in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to exclude spaces when validating a textbox in vb.net.
Here is the current ValidationExpressopn value:

ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.\']+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$" />

When user inputs space in textbox, I dont want that to render as error.

Example: I include spaces after "1@test.com   "

This should not be treater as incorrect data in the textbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your spaces are leading or trailing you can do a Trim on the expressionToValidate before comparing to your regexp

```
Dim expressionWithoutTrailingAndLeadingWhiteSpaces As String = originalExpression.Trim()
```

If you want to modify the regExp to take into account the trailing spaces:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})( *)$
```

If you want to exclude also leading spaces add an extra ( *) at the beginning of the expression:

```
^( *)[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})( *)$
```

Btw - the regExp you are providing is broken - I used the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369543/validating-e-mail-with-regular-expression-vb-net#369614) (expression to validate email addresses)

Comment: Is it possible to just include the validation inside the "ValidationExpression" in ascx?

Comment: Modified the reqExp directly to take into account trailing spaces

Comment: Thanks for the info. How about leading spaces? Is it possible to exclude those as well?

Comment: I modified the reg exp to include leading spaces - have fun