# Email Format Check in VB

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, email, email-validation

I want to check if email address is valid or not.

How can an email address be validated in VB using Regular Expressions?

```
([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating e-mail with regular expression VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369543/validating-e-mail-with-regular-expression-vb-net)

Comment: Shouldn't you simplify your question to, "how do I match a regular expression in VB.Net?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Function validateEmail(emailAddress) As Boolean

    Dim email As New Regex("([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})")
    If email.IsMatch(emailAddress) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
```

Comment: Why you ask question before try once?

Comment: Why not just `Return email.IsMatch(emailAddress)`

Answer (score 3):

MSDN Article: [How to: Verify That Email are in Valid E-Mail Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)

This example method calls the Regex.IsMatch(String, String) method to verify that the string conforms to a regular expression pattern.

```
Function IsValidEmailFormat(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(s, "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach without messing with **RegEx**, taken from my **[ElektroKit](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.Net/Tools/MailUtil.vb)** **API**:

[image]

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Validates a mail address.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim isValid As Boolean = ValidateMail("Address@Gmail.com")
''' Dim isValid As Boolean = ValidateMail("mailto:Address@Gmail.com")
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="address">
''' The mail address.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' <see langword="True"/> if the mail address is valid, <see langword="False"/> otherwise.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function ValidateMail(ByVal address As String) As Boolean

    If Not address.StartsWith("mailto:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        address = address.Insert(0, "mailto:")
    End If

    If Not Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(address, UriKind.Absolute) Then
        Return False
    End If

    Dim result As Uri = Nothing
    If Uri.TryCreate(address, UriKind.Absolute, result) Then
        Return (result.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeMailto)

    Else
        Return False

    End If

End Function
```

Note: I didn't performed a deep test with huge lists of emails.

---

If you preffer a regular expression, then **[this is my own](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.Text.RegEx/Tools/Patterns.vb)** following **[Wikipedia especifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)**, it gives me better results than other "universal" expressions, however, this expression is not perfectlly constructed, it doesn't avoid for example the double-dot conflict specified in **Wikipedia**, but we assume that will not encounter strange naming exceptions like that.

This expression never gave me a false positive (by the moment), but as any other **Regex** expr, use it at your own risk:

[image]

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' A pattern that matches an e-mail address.
''' <para></para>
''' 
''' For Example:
''' <para></para>
''' <c>local@domain.com</c>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Const EMail As String =
    "^(?<address>(?<local>[\d\w!#\$%\&'\*\+-/=\?\^_`\\\|~""\(\),:;\<\>@\[\]\{\}\.]+)@(?<domain>[\d\w-\.]+)\..+)$"
```